# Can't align link next to p in footer

Tags: html, css

Right now I am trying to align my links next to a p in the footer. For some reason all the links in the nav aligned easily however when I try to put a link next to the p in the footer. The link goes to the bottom. I have tried making my footer inline, I have tried different position methods, and I have tried floats. However making the footer inline-block did slightly improve the situation by getting rid of the ugly white stripe below. But I still need to get the link to align right. Here is the html code for my footer

```
<div id="footer">

          <p><b>Copyright 2011 Hometown Bank, Inc.</b></p>
          <a href="google.com">Privacy Policy</a>
</div>
```

Here is the css for the footer.

```
#footer
        {
            spadding-top: 1px;
            height: 7%;
            background-color:#CCDDEE;
            width: 100%;
            display:inline-block;
            position:

        }
```

If you need more of the code or more information, please be sure to let me know.

Comment: Put the link *inside* the paragraph. (Paragraphs are block-level elements, so subsequent content is laid out below them.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry for asking such a newb question

Comment: It's `padding-top` instead of `spadding-top`, and remove `position:` if you don't use any value for that property.

Comment: The spadding was just a quick way I deactivate the css attribute when I am trying to isolate a problem. Position was just a careless mistake I forgot about when pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now you can do this easily as like this

**html**

```
    <div id="footer">

          <p><b>Copyright 2011 Hometown Bank, Inc.</b> <a href="google.com">Privacy Policy</a></p>

</div>
```

***[Demo Live](http://tinkerbin.com/qpB9S9VR)***

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` will have padding/margin and is display:block by default.  Therefore, the link would appear on a new line.  Change the `<p>` to a `<span>` instead and update your styles as needed.

```
<div id="footer">
      <span style="font-weight:bold">Copyright 2011 Hometown Bank, Inc.</span>
      <a href="http://example.com/">Privacy Policy</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily by coding [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/izaiasdotcom/KQujg/)